# Proof explanation: diam(cl(E)) = diam ( E)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Yesterday I posted a question on this site about proving diam($E$) = diam(cl($E$)).  A user posted his proof but there was some part that I don't get,  I commented on his proof but he didn't respond to me.  So I'm very curious about what I miss, his proof is posted below.  The part where diam($E$) $ \leq $ diam(cl($E$)) is immediate so he only shows the reverse inequality.

[image]

The part I don't get is how did he conclude that there is an open ball $B_d(p)$ contained in cl($E$)-$E$.  Cause if you let $E$ to be the interval $ (0,1)$ belong to $ \mathbb{R}$, then cl($E$)-$E$ =$ \{0,1 \}$ and by def, diam(cl($E$)-$E$) $ = 1 -0 = 1 > 0$.  But it is clear that there is no open ball contained in cl($E$) $- E$.

Can someone point out what I missed?  I'm really curious about this.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: You are right.  And that proof is garbage from the very begining.  If diam(cl A) > diam A then, yes it does follow that diam (cl (A) - A) > 0, but that is hardly surprising or interesting.  Consider A = (0,1) the cl(A) - A = {0,1} and diam {0,1} = 1 > 0.  So what?  "Clearly there exists an open ball"  Why?  clA - A need not be open.  In fact it's obvious that isn't as every neighbor hood *must* contain points of A.  So the the boundary of a set is not open, which should surprise utterly *no-one*.

Comment: @fleablood thank you for your confirmation I kept wondering about what I miss all night yesterday.  well, at least he had a good intention to help then.

Comment: Much more straightforward proof: Suppose  d=diam(cl(E)) > diam D = r.  Let p,q in cl(E) be such d(p,q) > r.  Then p and q are not both in E (as diam E = r) so p or q is accumulation point.  Wolog assume q is.  Then for e < d(p,q) -r will be the radius of containing point x in E.  d(p,q) <= d(p,x) + d(q,x) so d(p,x) > r so p is not in E so p is accumulation point.  So there exist neigherhoods of radius [d(p,q) -r]/2 so there are points y, z in E so that d(y,z) > r.  A contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I actually posted my proof for checking yesterday and I found a couple more ways to do it, but it's just that his proof is so different than other and that's why it captures my curiosity. :) thank you again.